# .NET Core 3.1.4 XUnit Integration tests failing randomly

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I'm trying to integration test a sample API, and want to use a copy of the actual database to do so.
Running tests one file at a time results in all succeeding. Executing *dotnet test* or running all tests with .NET test explorer results in some tests failing at random, though it's usually the Theories.

Info:

- DB: PostgreSql-docker image
- API: .NET Core 3.1.4
- Test framework: XUnit 2.4.0

Tried:

- Reducing the amount of tests in total [Same result]
- Making the httpClient static [Same result]
- Making the ConfigureWebHost async [Failed to do so]
- Not running the EnsureDeleted() method [All test except delete test works (Surprise surprise)]
- Deleting the testing database manually before running the tests [Works]

So as you can see I have found a workaround, but this is not sufficient. I wish to be able to run *dotnet test* from a build server without having to create workaround scripts.
My theory is that the multiple fixtures tries to delete and create the database multiple times and fails because the other tests are using it?

CustomWebApplicationFactory:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Api;
using DataAccess;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Tests.Api.Controllers
{
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                RemoveOriginalDbContextService(services);
                SetDbContextOptions(services);

                var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database context
                using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                    try
                    {
                        using (var dbContext = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<TestDatabaseContext>())
                        {
                            dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted(); //This will make random tests fail
                            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while initializing " +
                                            "database. Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void RemoveOriginalDbContextService(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext>));

            if (descriptor != null) services.Remove(descriptor);
        }

        private void SetDbContextOptions(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            /***
            * Gets the configuration from the appsettings.json placed in the Api folder.
            ***/
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            /***
            * This is to register the test database context as a service.
            * Not having it results in: "No service for type 'TestDatabaseContext' has been registered."
            ***/
            services.AddDbContext<TestDatabaseContext>();

            /***
            * These settings will be used to instansiate the TestDatabaseContext, 
            * as it takes DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> as a parameter in its constructor.
            * Not having it results in InvalidArgumentException when trying to instansiate the TestDatabaseContext (Dependency Injection)
            ***/
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("TestingDatabase")));
        }
    }
}
```

Example test class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Domain.DataModels;
using Xunit;
using Api;

namespace Tests.Api.Controllers
{
    public class JobTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        private const string JOBURI = "/jobs";

        public JobTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _client = factory.CreateClient();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Insert_WithValidTitle_ShouldReturnOkAndTheNewlyCreatedJob()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded project exist
            var projectId = 1011;
            string title = "Test";
            Job job = new Job
            {
                ProjectId = projectId,
                Title = title
            };

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(JOBURI, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(job));

            //Then
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var newJob = await TestUtilities.GetDeserializedResponseBody<Job>(httpResponse);
            Assert.Equal(title, newJob.Title);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Insert_WithoutProjectId_ShouldReturnBadRequest()
        {
            //Given
            Job job = new Job { Title = "Test" };

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(JOBURI, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(job));

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Insert_WithNonExistingProjectId_ShouldReturnBadRequest()
        {
            //Given
            Job job = new Job
            {
                ProjectId = 777777,
                Title = "Test"
            };

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(JOBURI, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(job));

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Insert_WithoutTitle_ShouldReturnBadRequest()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded project exist
            Job job = new Job { ProjectId = 1011 };

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(JOBURI, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(job));

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Insert_WithInvalidJson_ShouldReturnBadRequest()
        {
            //Given
            var invalidBody = new StringContent("{\"title\":\"Test\"", Encoding.Default, "application/json");

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(JOBURI, invalidBody);

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void GetByProjectId_WithValidProjectId_ShouldReturnAListOfSeededJobs()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded job exist
            var projectId = 1011;
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/byprojectId/" + projectId;

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var jobs = await TestUtilities.GetDeserializedResponseBody<List<Job>>(httpResponse);
            Assert.NotEmpty(jobs);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void GetByProjectId_WithInvalidProjectId_ShouldReturnEmptyList()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded job exist
            var projectId = 7777;
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/byprojectId/" + projectId;

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var jobs = await TestUtilities.GetDeserializedResponseBody<List<Job>>(httpResponse);
            Assert.Empty(jobs);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void GetById_WithValidId_ShouldReturnSeededJob()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded job exist
            var jobId = 1001;
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + jobId;

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var job = await TestUtilities.GetDeserializedResponseBody<Job>(httpResponse);
            Assert.NotNull(job);
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData(-1)]
        [InlineData(0)]
        [InlineData(99999999)]
        public async void GetById_WithInvalidNumericId_ShouldReturnNoContent(int invalidId)
        {
            //Given
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + invalidId;

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void GetById_WithInvalidAlphabeticId_ShouldReturnBadRequest()
        {
            //Given
            var invalidId = "invalidId";
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + invalidId;

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Update_WithNewTitle_ShouldReturnUpdatedJob()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded job exist
            var newJobTitle = "NewJobTitle";
            var jobId = 1002;
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + jobId;

            //When
            var jobResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);
            var job = await TestUtilities.GetDeserializedResponseBody<Job>(jobResponse);
            job.Title = newJobTitle;

            var httpResponse = await _client.PutAsync(jobUri, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(job));

            //Then
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var responseBody = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var updatedJob = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Job>(responseBody);
            Assert.Equal(newJobTitle, updatedJob.Title);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Update_WithNullTitle_ShouldReturnBadRequest()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded job exist
            var jobId = 1002;
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + jobId;

            //When
            var jobResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);
            var job = await TestUtilities.GetDeserializedResponseBody<Job>(jobResponse);
            job.Title = null;

            var httpResponse = await _client.PutAsync(jobUri, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(job));

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void Delete_WithValidId_ShouldReturnOk()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded job exist
            var jobId = 1003;
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + jobId;

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.DeleteAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData(-1)]
        [InlineData(0)]
        [InlineData(999999)]
        public async void Delete_WithInvalidId_ShouldReturnBadRequest(int invalidId)
        {
            //Given
            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + invalidId;

            //When
            var httpResponse = await _client.DeleteAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }

        [Fact]
        public async void FullCRUD()
        {
            //Given
            //Seeded project exist
            var job = new Job
            {
                Title = "TEST_JOB",
                ProjectId = 1012
            };

            //When
            var postHttpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(JOBURI, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(job));
            var newJob = await TestUtilities.GetDeserializedResponseBody<Job>(postHttpResponse);

            var jobUri = JOBURI + "/" + newJob.Id;
            var getHttpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(jobUri);
            getHttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            newJob.Title = "TEST_JOB_Updated";
            var putHttpResponse = await _client.PutAsync(jobUri, ContentHelper.GetStringContent(newJob));
            putHttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var deleteHttpResponse = await _client.DeleteAsync(jobUri);

            //Then
            deleteHttpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with a similar problem.
Tried all sorts of things like classfixtures, assign a new guid to the in memory database name each time to keep tests separate from each other etc.

In the end what fixed it for me was to put all my integration tests in a collection.

```
[Collection("Our Test Collection #1")]
public class TestClass1
{
 ...
}

[Collection("Our Test Collection #1")]
public class TestClass2
{
 ...
}
```

This ensures they won't be run in parallel against each other.
In my case it didn't make a big difference in performance and solved the failing batches of tests.

(for reference: https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel)